# How to do this practice exercise?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I am new in android programming. In this task,I should do what is shown in the picture,but without use a bitmap,only by making drawable xml files and show it in one layout. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: No! Sorry :) Not a free coding service!

Comment: I didn't ask any code,but the way to do so.Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can do it using shape drawables ([link to reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)) and textviews

Comment: You think so? Without any explantations? That is not a valid answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer MJB22 .I am in the same way with you!